# How do I use mock_models with RSpec outside of Rails?

Tags: ruby, activerecord, rspec

I am currently working on a Ruby project that comprises of a Redis DB, EventMachine and Sinatra (for a lightweight API). We're using RSpec for our testing and up until this point, everything has been going great.

Now, however, we need to start talking (minimally) to a MySQL database. We've decided to go the route of ActiveRecord (just because it's **SO** nice!) and everything is going smooth so far. However, we are running into a small problem with our tests. I found some resources online using `mock_model` and `mock` with RSpec but, I keep getting:

```
undefined method `mock_model'
undefined method `mock'
```

errors. What gem to I need to use for these to work without installing the entire Rails framework (just seems like overkill).

**OR**

What other mocking/stubing methods/gems should I be using to mock my AR models? I really enjoy the flexibility of a syntax like:

```
@user = double(NS::UserAccount)
@car = double(NS::Car)
NS::UserAccount.stub(:find).with(@valid_user_id).return(@user)
NS::Car.stub(:find).with(@valid_car_id).return(@car)
```

**UPDATE**

My Gemfile looks like the following:

```
group :test do
  gem 'rspec',                '~> 2.8.0'
  gem 'rspec-expectations',   '~> 2.8.0'
  gem 'rspec-mocks',          '~> 2.8.0'      
  gem 'autotest-standalone'
  gem 'em-spec',              '~> 0.2.6'
  gem 'rack-test',            '~> 0.6.1'
  gem 'factory_girl',         '~> 3.1.0'
end
```

Also, at the top of the `spec_helper.rb` file, I have the following:

```
require 'bundler/setup'
Bundler.require(:test, :development)
```

Comment: Are you using Bundler to manage your dependencies? If so, what does your dependency on rspec look like in your Gemfile? What require statements do you have in your spec_helper.rb file?

Note that the mocking capabilities are in separate gems (rspec-mocks for mock and rspec-rails for mock_model). So if you have a dependency on just rspec-core (for example) it might explain why it can't find these methods.

Comment: @BrianPloetz - I updated the question. So I guess I need to update my Gemfile to be more explicit because when I run `bundle`, I still see `rspec-mocks`, `rspec-expectations`, etc.

Comment: Ok, so I made my Gemfile mor explicit, but I'm still not having much luck.

Comment: Found the answer to my problem (sort-of). Looks like I was trying to use mock/double/stub in the before(:all) which it doesn't work. See https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/issues/92#issuecomment-3178470. However, I still can't get mock_model to work (seems to be part of the rspec-rails extensions).

Comment: What do you have in your RSpec.configure? Do you have this line 'config.mock_with :rspec'?

Comment: @megas Well, the previous comment I made on here discusses solving my problem with `mock` and `double` however, I still cannot get `mock_models` working correctly and your answer below led me down a rabbit whole that ended in a big mess that I refuse to deal with in an ongoing fashion.

Comment: Maybe you should raise the bounty to have reason to solve this problem. Also you can create the test project on github so everybody can see what's in your project. Once again, do you have connected active_record and rspec to your project?

Comment: @megas Yes I do. Honestly if the +50 bounty doesn't get it and no one finds this question with similar goals to mine, then I have to wonder if I am doing something incorrect. (I'm sorry the 50 bounty doesn't make it worth your time...) The sheer lack of resources for this particular issue online makes me wonder what everyone else's solutions consist of.

Answer (score 0):

For the Active Record models RSpec has method `mock_model`, which automatically creates several stubs, common for all Ruby on Rails models, and accepts hash.

So to use `mock_model` outside of Rails you should have connected Active Record and [rspec-rails](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails) extension.

To make sure you can look at [here](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/blob/master/lib/rspec/rails/mocks.rb) where's `mock_model` is defined.

Comment: Yeah, I've gotten that far. I have all of my models as AR models and I have rspec-rails included into my project. The issue is when it starts complaining that there are undefined constants. Is the solution to define all of the constants as empty modules/classes? If so, what kind of issues might that cause. I'm really looking for a good resource of someone who has used `mock_model` outside of Rails.

Comment: Look at this article http://ben-tech.blogspot.com/2010/08/use-mockmodel-outside-of-rails.html

Comment: Note: That blog post is a couple of years old, and the constant names don't correspond to the current rspec-rails constants.

It should be simple enough to define the missing constants, with the only caveat being watch out for modules vs constants. Then do a guarded definition of whatever it is requiring `unless defined? Rails...`.

Comment: After defining like 20 classes/modules. I'm starting to think that this is not the correct approach. There are WAY too many missing constants. Has anyone actually attempted this solution? If so, what was your EXACT approach? All these suggestions sound like guesses.